# Parsing a hash to print into a nicely formatted string

Tags: ruby, hash, tostring

I have the following array (which is part of a much larger hash):

```
[{"type"=>"work", "value"=>"work@work.com"}, {"type"=>"home", "value"=>"home@home.com"}, {"type"=>"home", "value"=>"home2@home2.com"}]
```

I would like somehow take that and convert it to a neatly formatted string such as:

```
Work: work@work.com, Home: home@home.com, Home: home2@home2.com
```

The issue is that this array will now always be the same, sometime it will have 2 emails, sometimes 5, sometimes none. And what is worse is that there can even be duplicates. two home emails for example.

Comment: How should the output look like if there are multiple emails or multiple home entries? Can you give an example?

Comment: @hek2mgl done. Doesn't need to be anything that special. Thanks!

Comment: You told `This issue is ...`

Comment: Ok, your edit explained it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following code:

```
array = [{"type"=>"work", "value"=>"work@work.com"}, {"type"=>"home", "value"=>"home@home.com"}]

string = array.map do |item|
    item = "#{item['type'].capitalize}: #{item['value']}"
end.join(", ")

puts string
```

*Output:*

```
Work: work@work.com, Home: home@home.com, Home: home2@home2.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
arr = [{ "type"=>"work",    "value"=>"work@work.com"    },
       { "type"=>"home",    "value"=>"home@home.com"    },
       { "type"=>"cottage", "value"=>"cot1@cottage.com" },
       { "type"=>"home",    "value"=>"home2@home2.com"  },
       { "type"=>"cottage", "value"=>"cot2@cottage.com" }]

h = arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g["type"]=>[g["value"]]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {"work"=>["work@work.com"],
  #    "home"=>["home@home.com", "home2@home2.com"],
  #    "cottage"=>["cot1@cottage.com", "cot2@cottage.com"]}

puts h.map { |k,v| "#{k.capitalize}: #{v.join(', ')}" }.join("\n")
  # Work: work@work.com
  # Home: home@home.com, home2@home2.com
  # Cottage: cot1@cottage.com, cot2@cottage.com
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.